# android common OnItemClickListener and separate button listeners

Tags: android, include, onclick, onitemclicklistener

In my app I have around 12 activities. The first layout of my activity is a list view. By clicking each list it gets redirected to other activities. I have implemented the Listview with OnItemClickListener and is working good.

In all the other 11 activities, I have a common title bar with a logo and a button named as S. When the user clicks on the S button, I am showing the same list of items in the First activity of my app, within the current activities by splitting the page. Now *instead of writing a separate `OnItemClickListener` for each activity, how to write it once and use in multiple activities*?

In the same way I have placed `3 button in include layout` and I am using this in various activities, *how to write a separate common button action, it can be used in multiple activities.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While @SamirMangroliya's method works, this is an alternate method you can use, and the one I've been using for a while.

Create your listener in another class file (say, `MyClickListener.java`):

```
public class MyClickListener implements OnItemClickListener {
    // This can be OnClickListener, OnTouchListener, whatever you like.
    // Implement your method here:
    public onItemClick(...) {
        // Your selection process, etc.
    }
}
```

Then in each of your `Activity` objects, all you have to do is:

```
myObject.setOnItemClickListener(new MyClickListener());
```

Comment: thanx for your reply. I have a doubt, in class for List click listener i have added this....

Comment: Intent myIntent = new Intent(ActivityTab.this, MyProfile.class);
myIntent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(myIntent);
finish();

Comment: Eric - i am getting error in ActivityTab.this, startActivity and finish() how to overcome this errors

Comment: Pass your `Activity` to the constructor of this listener, save it, then access those methods through it.

Answer (score 1):

**how to write a separate common button action, it can be used in multiple activities.**

you should create one Activity(called BaseActivity),

```
class BaseActivity extends Activity{

@Override
public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
     super.setContentView(layoutResID);

  Button btn1 = (Button)findViewById(r.id.btn1);
  .
  .
  .  

  //now setonclickListner here...
}

}
```

then extends it ...`class MyActivity extends BaseActivity`

Comment: is there any sample code or tutorial for this, when i tried this my app get crashed saying null pointer exception in a line..,

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should implement [ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) navigation.  For a more detailed description about how to do it the Android way, see the [Design](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html) guide.  To support versions of Android between 1.6 and 2.3, link in the [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) library.